# OmniPay Paypal Express Checkout Phone not Passed

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, omnipay

I can't seem to pass the shippingPhone or billingPhone to put it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rwtr.png)

This is my code

```
    $cardInput = array(
        'firstName' => 'John',
        'lastName'  => 'Doe',
        'billingAddress1' => 'My Address',
        'billingPhone'  =>  'XXXXXXX', //or the shippingPhone
        'billingCity'   =>  'Miami',
        'billingState'  =>  'Florida',
        'billingPostCode'   => '33133',
        'email'     =>  'email@gmail.com',
    );

    $card = Omnipay::creditCard($cardInput);
    $response = Omnipay::purchase([
        'amount' => '100.00',
        'returnUrl' => 'http://site.org/?return=success',
        'cancelUrl' => 'http://site.org/?return=canceled',
        'card' => $card,
        'description'=>'This is the description',
    ])->send();
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the raw request and response generated from the code?

Comment: Hi @AndrewAngell, this is the end of the request

....UEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=VA&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=22079&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=111-111-1111&EMAIL=myemail%40gmail.com